# Should node_modules be in User folder or project folders?

Tags: node.js, module, node-modules

I am a total Javascript newbie aiming to configure my Mac nicely for development.
NPM is installed.

I notice that folder `node_modules` exists in my `Users/MyName` directory.

I *think* this is a result of having either installed Node/NPM or specifically run `npm install airtable` the other day, which I did at the time in `Users/MyName`.

When I `npm uninstall airtable`, it removes `airtable` and its dependency folders from `nodule_modules`, leaving the following: `@types` and `package-lock.json` (hidden).

If I `cd` to new project-specific directory `Users/MyName/Projects/Code/myusername/airtable-test` and run `npm install airtable` from there, I expected the packages may get installed in that folder. However, again, they get installed up at `Users/MyName/node_modules`.

In both cases, `.package-lock.json` (non-hidden) and `package.json` are in `Users/MyName`, which seems messy to me. (I haven't done anything non-standard in install).

Is this the way things should be?

Attempts to solve:

I seem to [read](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/folders), including from questions on Stackoverflow, that storing modules at `Users/MyName/node_modules` is effectively storing them globally, accessible to any app, and such that projects don't have to get committed to server with all dependencies in tow - the [idea being that](https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/9o5fzk/what_is_node_modules_used_for/e7rwd8u/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), after you deploy your app, you then run `npm install` whilst in its folder, prompting it to install all dependencies.

Is this right? Should I be looking at storing all dependency modules in a project folder, or above and outside of it?

(If the answer to this question is opinion-based, I wasn't aware of that).

Comment: Did you run `npm init` or create a `package.json` inside the project directory? I would always store a project's dependencies under said project directory, as the versions of the packages may differ across projects. You usually add `node_modules` to `.gitignore` as they are not needed in source control - the package.json + package-lock.json ensures you can get install the right versions again when you need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I believe is happening. You have your `package.json` in folder `Users/MyName` and you are running npm install in `Users/MyName/Projects/Code/myusername/airtable-test`. But the problem is you do not have `package.json` file in the folder `Users/MyName/Projects/Code/myusername/airtable-test`. So npm goes up in the directory to find the `package.json` and it found it in `Users/MyName` so it is installing the package there.

This is happening because the way npm identifies a project is by looking for `package.json`. If it does not find it in current directory than it assumes that you must be inside some sub directory of the project and start searching upwards in the folder hierarchy to find the `package.json`.

**solution**

Do `npm init` in the folder `Users/MyName/Projects/Code/myusername/airtable-test`. This will initialize the folder as a npm package (by creating package.json).

Comment: So, I should delete `node_modules`, `package.json` and `package_lock.json` from `Users/MyName`? When I do this, I just found that `npm install airtable`, when _in_ the project directory, actually creates `package.json` by itself (no need for `npm init`), as well as `package_lock.json` and `node_modules` in the project folder. That said, it doesn't populate `package.json` with fields like `name` and `description`, just `dependencies`. /// So, two responses here suggest modules should be stored on a per-project basis, rather than globally.

Comment: I actually never tried installing a npm package without doing `npm init`. So that is something I learnt today. Yes, node_module are stored per project basis. You can install packages globally but then that would not be listed in your package.json hanse will not be part of your package's dependencies.